# Are $f(x)=1$ and $f(x)=x$ homeomorphic in $(\Bbb R^2,d_r)$?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

I was given a task to determine whether these two spaces are homeomorphic in  $(\Bbb R^2,d_r)$, ($d_r$ is Jungle River Metric Space).
So far I've found a function "between" them, which is $f(x,y)=(x,1)$, but I have problems with proving whether it is a homeomorphism or not.
[image]

Can you give me any advice on how I can approach this exercise? I've tried checking the continuity of the function $f(x,y)$, but I didn't know how to properly do that.

Comment: These are functions. Do you mean the graphs of these functions?

Comment: @AlekosRobotis Yes, I mean the graphs.

Comment: @bobbyshmurda i really love your user name, lmao

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: only one of these two spaces is discrete.